# Unable to understand Laravel and react js bootstrap code

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, reactjs, laravel-5

Following is the code included in bootstrap of laravel code. Can anyone please explain it to me. Thanks.

```
window._ = require('lodash');//whats "window._"  and lodash?
 try {
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');//wher is this ans its use?
 } catch (e) {}
window.axios = require('axios'); whats "window.axios"  and where is axios?
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

What is `window.axios.defaults.headers.common`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window._ = require('lodash');` assigns `lodash` to the variable `_` on the [window Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). This means that any javascript executed in the browser afterwards has access to the lodash library using the `_` variable.

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');` is the same thing, but for jQuery. However here it is assigned to both `window.$` and `window.jQuery`, because jQuery can be used in both ways.

`require('bootstrap-sass')` loads the bootstrap theme using sass, provided by [this package](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#readme)

`window.axios = require('axios');` loads axios, into the variable `axios` on the window object, just as the first two. [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is a javascript HTTP Client used to get data from or send data to servers from your javascript.

The last one, `window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` configures axios to always send an [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) with the requests. So every request it makes will have the HTTP header:

`"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"`

I'm not sure why this is the default.